# How to convert a tuple into a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tuples

I have a tuple that contains a numpy array that I want to convert into just the numpy array. The current tuple is:

```
Tup = (array([ 7500, 10476, 10643, 13683, 14761]),)
```

i've tried using the `np.asarray` module but when I do this it just adds an array around the tuple instead of removing it as seen below:

```
Tup= np.asarray(Tup)
print(Tup)
Output: array([[ 7500, 10476, 10643, 13683, 14761]])
```

How would I convert Tup into just an array. My ideal output would be:

```
[7500, 10476, 10643, 13683, 14761]
```

Comment: Just select the first element of the tuple `Tup[0]`

Comment: How about `Tup[0]`? Or do you actually want a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have an 1-tuple containing an array as the single element; just index with zero to get the first (zeroth) element to select the array:

```
arr = Tup[0]
```

To get to a bare Python list (as per your "ideal output"),

```
arr = list(Tup[0])
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

```py
list(Tup[0])
```

Extract the numpy array from the tuple and convert it into a list

Answer (score 1):

It's actually bit easier. What you need to do is simply use this code & it's done.   `array_from_tuple = np.array(tuple_name)`
where tuple_name is the name assigned to the object. For more features you can refer to this syntax:

```
numpy.array( object, dtype = None, *, copy = True, order = ‘K’, subok = False, ndmin = 0 )
```

Thanks for A2A!
Keep exploring!